# How can I reduce these four lines of code that splits/trims a semicolon list to one line?

Tags: c#, split

How can I do this:

```
string list = "one; two; three;four";

List<string> values = new List<string>();
string[] tempValues = list.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string tempValue in tempValues)
{
    values.Add(tempValue.Trim());
}
```

in one line, something like this:

```
List<string> values = extras.Split(';').ToList().ForEach( x => x.Trim()); //error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Select` if you want to perform a transformation on each instance in the `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
List<string> values = list.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: You need a ToList() at the end, since Select returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`

Comment: @Tinister, Thomas: Thanks, I realized that shortly after I posted the answer. I've since updated it.

Answer (score 3):

Easy -- use the LINQ select method:

```
var values = "one; two; three;four".Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(str => str.Trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> values = new List<string>(list.Split(new char[] { ';', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

No explicit `Trim()` is necessary.  Nor is LINQ.  Add `\t`, `\r`, `\n` to the char[] if other whitespace may be present.

Comment: Interesting idea, but fails for cases like `"twenty;twenty one;twenty two"`. Spaces are often present in semicolon delimited lists.

Comment: Fair enough!  Although, pedantically-speaking, he did ask about a very specific string.  ;)

Comment: @JMD: If you really want to go there, then an easier solution would be `new List<string>() {"one", "two", "three", "four"};`